# How to dismiss view controller after login Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscenedelegate

I am trying to dismiss a view controller after the user has logged in successfully, but so far it is crashing in the Home view controller when I set `tableView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad()`. This is the code I use after a successful login:

`self.view.window?.rootViewController = HomeVC()`

This is the logic I have in `SceneDelegate` to present the login View Controller if the user is not signed in:

```
if(Auth.auth().currentUser == nil){
            window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
            window?.windowScene = windowScene
            window?.rootViewController = OnboardingVC()
        }
```

How can I dismiss the `OnboardingVC` after a successful login?

Here is the error log from the crash:

```
screen parameters are unexpected: MGScreenClass1125x2436x3x495 SCREEN_TYPE(1125,2436,3,495)

CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: ''

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will dismiss all the presented view controllers and remain root view controller:

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

If you present the view using modal, try this:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you present the view using "push" segue, try this:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I am not presenting the view controller, I am making setting the rootViewController to it in SceneDelegate, now I do not know how to change it back after login